# Foreign keys with mysql is it possible to have a foreign key based on value of column?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I have this database structure,

```
SET SQL_MODE="NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `announces` (
   `tracker` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
   `failCount` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
   PRIMARY KEY (`tracker`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `hashes` (
   `hash` binary(20) NOT NULL,
   `indexed` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
   PRIMARY KEY (`hash`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `trackers` (
   `hash` binary(20) NOT NULL,
   `tracker` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
   `seeders` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
   `leechers` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
   KEY `hashFK` (`hash`),
   KEY `trackerFK` (`tracker`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

ALTER TABLE `trackers`
   ADD CONSTRAINT `hashFK` FOREIGN KEY (`hash`) REFERENCES `hashes` (`hash`)
   ON DELETE CASCADE,
   ADD CONSTRAINT `trackerFK` FOREIGN KEY (`tracker`) REFERENCES `announces` (`tracker`) 
   ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

The table trackers has 2 foreign keys one for trackers, and one for hashes.

This I think makes sure that a hash cannot be in trackers without first being in hashes. And if a hash is deleted from hashes then it also gets deleted from trackers.

Same for trackers, a tracker must exist in announces before it can exist in trackers, and if it gets deleted from announces it also gets deleted from trackers.

The problem I have is that a hash should only exist in trackers if the corresponding value of `indexed` in the `hashes` row is `== 1`. Is this possible?

Comment: would you like to set indexed = 1 onto the hash whenever a tracker is inserted with a fk toward it? Or maybe you'd prefer to raise an error whenever a tracker is inserted with a fk to a hash with indexed != 1?

Comment: Preferably the latter, as far as I understanded the manual I didn't think I could add triggers with foreign keys? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you wish is to raise an error whenever a tracker is inserted with a fk to a hash with indexed != 1, then it has to be implemented at the applicative layer.

Various options:

- favorite coding language checks (subsequent queries to check values before insertions)
- using triggers, before insert into tracker, check that the corresponding hash is indexed, and if not cancel/raise error

cheers

Comment: But maybe a more global analysis should be performed? Maybe whenever a hash is indexed it should have a tracker immediatly inserted with? Maybe when the user decides to create a tracker from a hash, he should only have the choice of selecting indexed hashes? I don't know the nature of your system but you got my point.

Comment: Ye this makes sense, just gonna have to tweak alot of things to get it to work :)